# Demonstration of the Acceptance-Rejection method in the case of a beta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, monte-carlo

The goal is to simulate the realization of the density of probability of the beta law $\beta(2,2)$ using the algorithm of Accept-Reject Methods

Show that if we give ourselves an i.i.d. sequence $(Y_i,U_i)$ with $Y_i$ and $U_i$ independent of uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, then X has the same distribution as $Y_N$ or $N= inf\{i, \frac{3}{2}U_i \leq f(Y_i;2,2) \}$.

I am stuck in this demonstration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "the same distribution as $Y_N$ or $N= inf\{i, \frac{3}{2}U_i \leq f(Y_i;2,2) \}$" looks strangely written, but presumably means that you only accept those $Y_i$ with $\frac{3}{2}U_i \leq f(Y_i;2,2)$.  This looks like typical rejection sampling.  What have your tried?